# Is there a way to extract Apple Game Center achievement icon?

Tags: game-center

I found several Apple Game Center achievement icons I want to use in a walkthrough. Is there a way to extract them? I tried looking into system directory but found nothing. I suppose these images are stored in cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are stored on Apple's GC server and then downloaded as required.  I assume there is a system cache somewhere, but it's not something that is discussed in the docs.  Apps can request the icons to make up their own achievement UI but they don't need to store them in the bundle.